# ShareThis facebook share to show single image only

Tags: html, facebook

I am using the Facebook share functionality of ShareThis to create a share function on a webpage. Though I have specified a single `og:image` property, I still get some other undesired images in the facebook share window. Below is my code:-

In the meta head:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/logo.png" />
```

The Facebook ShareThis button:

```
<span class="st_facebook_custom" st_processed="yes"><img alt="purple-facebook.png" src="/catalog/view/theme/default/images/sharethis/purple-facebook.png"> </span>
```

How can I make it so that the facebook share window only shows a single "logo.png"?

Comment: Does your defined logo have the required minimal width and height?

Comment: Try passing your URL through the Facebook debugger??

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug